# store variables as one line in output file python

Tags: python

I am trying to store three different variables(which are results from a for loop) as one line in a file. My entire code just in case you wondering what I am trying to do :

```
from Bio.PDB import *
from Bio import SeqIO
from glob import glob
parser = PDBParser(PERMISSIVE=True)
pdb_files = glob('/pdb_RF0001/*')

for fileName in pdb_files:
    structure_id = fileName.rsplit('/', 1)[1][:-4]
    structure = parser.get_structure(structure_id, fileName)
    model = structure[0]
    for residue1 in structure.get_residues():
        for residue2 in structure.get_residues():
            if residue1 != residue2:
                try:
                    distance = residue1['P'] - residue2['P']
                except KeyError:
                    continue
                f = open('%s.txt' % fileName, 'w')
                line = str(residue1)+','+str(residue2)+','+str(distance)
                f.write(line)
                f.close()
            break
```

Sample code for check :

```
f = open('%s.txt' % fileName, 'wb')
line = int(residue1)+','+int(residue)+','+float(distance)
f.write(line)
f.close()
```

How to store the three different variables from the line variable as one line in an output file?

Comment: How can you add `int` type to `str` type?

Comment: Your code seems to work. So, what is the problem?

Comment: @HotteShen What his code seems to works?  How does it run? OP just added `int` type with `str` type.

Comment: If you are creating a CSV, there is a package you can use to read in and out csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `f-string`

```
line = f"{residue1}, {residue}, {distance}"
```

Comment: It is showing 

 f.write(line)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'..any idea how to resolve this.

Comment: @shome use `f = open('%s.txt' % fileName, 'w')`, mode is `w`, not `wb`

Answer (score 1):

`int(residue)` is an integer, and `float(distance)` is a real number (specifically, a floating-point number, hence the "`float`"). Thus, in this line, you are trying to add numbers to strings:

```py
line = int(residue1)+','+int(residue)+','+float(distance)
```

However, Python disallows this. What you probably want to do is convert `residue1`, `residue`, and `distance` from (what I assume are) numbers *to* strings, like this:

```py
line = str(residue1)+','+str(residue)+','+str(distance)
```

Comment: It is showing     f.write(line)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: Use "`w`" instead of "`wb`" in your call to `open()`.

Answer (score 0):

**str.format()** is one of the string formatting methods in Python

```
"{}, {}, {}".format("residue1", "residue", "distance")
```